# SIGSEGV 'SEGV_MAPERR' crash inside my app that is on apple store

Tags: segmentation-fault, armv7, ios8.1, crittercism, objc-message-send

My app is on app store and i have enabled critticism inside my app. Following crash reported:

```
Threads
_________________________________
Thread: Unknown Name (Crashed)
0     libobjc.A.dylib                       0x00000001973f7bdc objc_msgSend + 28
1     UIKit                                 0x000000018b59952c -[UIKeyboardImpl centerFilled] + 88
2     UIKit                                 0x000000018b90eb00 -[UIKBBackgroundView refreshStyleForKeyplane:inputTraits:] + 300
3     UIKit                                 0x000000018b599284 -[UIKeyboardLayoutStar updateBackgroundIfNeeded] + 384
4     UIKit                                 0x000000018b591cc4 -[UIKeyboardLayoutStar setKeyplaneName:] + 2672
5     UIKit                                 0x000000018b4d2f7c -[UIKeyboardLayoutStar setShift:] + 180
6     UIKit                                 0x000000018b4d2ca8 -[UIKeyboardImpl notifyShiftState] + 84
7     CoreFoundation                        0x0000000186c92a50 __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_AN_OBSERVER_CALLBACK_FUNCTION__ + 28
8     CoreFoundation                        0x0000000186c8f9dc __CFRunLoopDoObservers + 356
9     CoreFoundation                        0x0000000186c8fd24 __CFRunLoopRun + 680
10   CoreFoundation                         0x0000000186bbd0a4 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 392
11   GraphicsServices                       0x000000018fd675a4 GSEventRunModal + 164
12   UIKit                                  0x000000018b4f23c0 UIApplicationMain + 1484
13   Eventi                                 0x00000001000e6e80 main (main.m:16)
14   libdyld.dylib                          0x0000000197a52a08 start + 0

Thread: Unknown Name
0     libsystem_kernel.dylib                0x0000000197b50c94 kevent64 + 8
1     libdispatch.dylib                     0x0000000197a2b3b4 _dispatch_mgr_thread + 48

Thread: Unknown Name
0     Eventi                                0x000000010034bce0 mach_exception_callback + 188
1     Eventi                                0x0000000100358054 exception_server_thread + 304
2     libsystem_pthread.dylib               0x0000000197c07e80 _pthread_body + 160
3     libsystem_pthread.dylib               0x0000000197c07ddc _pthread_start + 156
4     libsystem_pthread.dylib               0x0000000197c04fb0 thread_start + 0

Thread: Unknown Name
0     libsystem_kernel.dylib                0x0000000197b50e7c mach_msg_trap + 8
1     CoreFoundation                        0x0000000186c91ed0 __CFRunLoopServiceMachPort + 196
2     CoreFoundation                        0x0000000186c8fe24 __CFRunLoopRun + 936
3     CoreFoundation                        0x0000000186bbd0a4 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 392
4     CFNetwork                             0x00000001866c24e8 +[NSURLConnection(Loader) _resourceLoadLoop:] + 436
5     Foundation                            0x0000000187badc0c __NSThread__main__ + 1068
6     libsystem_pthread.dylib               0x0000000197c07e80 _pthread_body + 160
7     libsystem_pthread.dylib               0x0000000197c07ddc _pthread_start + 156
8     libsystem_pthread.dylib               0x0000000197c04fb0 thread_start + 0

Thread: Unknown Name
0     libsystem_kernel.dylib                0x0000000197b6b498 __select + 8
1     libsystem_pthread.dylib               0x0000000197c07e80 _pthread_body + 160
2     libsystem_pthread.dylib               0x0000000197c07ddc _pthread_start + 156
3     libsystem_pthread.dylib               0x0000000197c04fb0 thread_start + 0

Thread: Unknown Name
0     libsystem_kernel.dylib                0x0000000197b50e7c mach_msg_trap + 8
1     CoreFoundation                        0x0000000186c91ed0 __CFRunLoopServiceMachPort + 196
2     CoreFoundation                        0x0000000186c8fe24 __CFRunLoopRun + 936
3     CoreFoundation                        0x0000000186bbd0a4 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 392
4     Foundation                            0x0000000187ac5804 -[NSRunLoop(NSRunLoop) runMode:beforeDate:] + 312
5     Foundation                            0x0000000187b1fef8 -[NSRunLoop(NSRunLoop) run] + 92
6     Eventi                                0x00000001000c7470 +[AFURLConnectionOperation networkRequestThreadEntryPoint:] (AFURLConnectionOperation.m:162)
7     Foundation                            0x0000000187badc0c __NSThread__main__ + 1068
8     libsystem_pthread.dylib               0x0000000197c07e80 _pthread_body + 160
9     libsystem_pthread.dylib               0x0000000197c07ddc _pthread_start + 156
10   libsystem_pthread.dylib                0x0000000197c04fb0 thread_start + 0

Thread: Unknown Name
0     libsystem_kernel.dylib                0x0000000197b6bc78 __workq_kernreturn + 8
1     libsystem_pthread.dylib               0x0000000197c04fa8 start_wqthread + 0

Thread: Unknown Name
0     libsystem_kernel.dylib                0x0000000197b6bc78 __workq_kernreturn + 8
1     libsystem_pthread.dylib               0x0000000197c04fa8 start_wqthread + 0

Thread: Unknown Name
0     libsystem_kernel.dylib                0x0000000197b6bc78 __workq_kernreturn + 8
1     libsystem_pthread.dylib               0x0000000197c04fa8 start_wqthread + 0

Thread: Unknown Name
0     libsystem_kernel.dylib                0x0000000197b6bc78 __workq_kernreturn + 8
1     libsystem_pthread.dylib               0x0000000197c04fa8 start_wqthread + 0
```

Is there any way out to get this crash solved ? Also i am not able to reproduce this crash by enabling `Zoombie` or `malloc guard`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried to run it in release mode (default is debug -> hold on your app name in top left xCode corner, select edit scheme, select run tab, change build configuration to release, don't forget to switch it back to debug later).

Seems like an issue with changing the default keyboard to the different one. Open the AppStore, download custom keyboard (eg. Swype, it's popular so there's high chance it's crashing on it) and try to change it while in your app.

Comment: Thanks. I have used 3 different keyboards, changing from default keyboard to the different one and vice versa, but my app didn't crashed. If it crashed, then what will be its solution to get it fixed ?

Comment: Have you tried in release mode? I don't know, depends what exactly is happening. Are you sure it isn't crash from the custom keyboard instead of your app? Seems like some layout inside keyboard got messed up. Is the crash frequent?

Comment: Yes i have tried in release mode. No crash is not frequent. it happens almost one times a month. you can say crash percentage is almost 2%. But i need to resolve it. Is i am using some parameter that is not thread safe.? But how can i check inside whole app which property is not accurate ?

Comment: For me it looks like the keyboard 'shift' (arrow up) button is pressed, all buttons change from small to capital and the crash happens. I'd guess it's connected with custom keyboards. Now there are 2 possibilities: it's something your app can't handle or it's keyboard bad implementation. If it is case 2, you cannot fix it as it's not your app. Otherwise probably you'd need more information about this crash to fix it. 1 crash per month isn't bad, so I'd probably just leave it as long as it's so rare.